# Solution of recursive differential equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I have to integrate:
$$dX_{t} = \alpha X_{t-1}dt$$
But I don't know if this should be interpreted as
$$\frac{1}{X_{t-1}}dX_{t} = \alpha dt$$
How can this $X_{t-1}$ be integrated w.r.t $dX_t$? Or how can it be integrated as $\alpha X_{t-1}dt$?

Comment: I think your question has got a little confused. Do you mean to start with $\frac{d}{dt} f_k(t) = \alpha f_{k-1}(t),$ and then solve this equation by $f_k(t) = \frac{1}{k!}(\alpha t)^k$? If this is the case, you should edit your question to make it more clear. Then the second equation you have,  $\frac{d}{dt} X_t = \alpha X_{t-1},$ this is currently a very different type of equation because it doesn't depend on $k$. I wonder if you copied this one down wrong?

Comment: How is the second equation $\frac{d}{dt}X_t = \alpha X_{t-1}$ calculated?

Comment: As I explained in my previous comment, your question is not well written and I think it may have mistakes. If you want to solve $\frac{d}{dt}X_t = \alpha X_{t-1}$ then that's fine, but this is a very different type of equation to the first one you give. If you edit your question to address the points I've raised, I will try to help you with your problem

Comment: I have edited it. I'm very confused with this, hope you can help me...

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that what you have here is a delay differential equation. I would consider dividing by $dt$ to write it as $$\frac{d}{dt}X_t = \alpha X_{t-1},$$ which is similar to the example considered [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation#The_Characteristic_Equation), at the end of the section 'The Characteristic Equation'. I think you then want to consider $X_t$ as a function of $t$, and integrate in $t$ to solve.

As in that example, try an ansatz of the form $X_t=Ae^{\lambda t}$. Substituting this into the equation gives a characteristic equation of the form $$\lambda =\alpha e^{-\lambda},$$ which can be solved for $\lambda$ in terms of the Lambert W function. Rearranging gives $\lambda e^{\lambda} =\alpha,$ with solution $\lambda = W(\alpha)$.

Then your original equation has solution $$X_t=Ae^{W(\alpha) t}.$$

Comment: @Sinem if you're happy with my answer, can you press the tick next to the voting arrows to accept it?